# Adding ViewController as a subView in a UITableViewCell - Not showing up

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, subview

I'm trying to add a ViewController to my TableView cell however it is not showing up when testing.

PhotoLocation is a UIViewController subclass. I have a View Controller created on the StoryBoard with a bunch of UILabels, UITextFields, UISwitch, etc configured on it. PhotoLocation is associated with that StoryBoard View Controller and its Identifier is PhotoLocation.

In a separate controller - UITableViewController, I have a working TableView with cells that are populating with various information, I am trying to add the PhotoLocation VC as a subview of each cell. (Note: PhotoLocation is a freeform sized VC that is of size 210x100).

In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I'm doing the following:

```
// snip code above which sets up the cell and performs various other things

PhotoLocation *photoLocation_ = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PhotoLocation"];
[photoLocation_.view setFrame:CGRectMake(115, 0, 210, 109)];
[cell.contentView addSubview:photoLocation_.view];

return cell;
```

When I run the app the subview does not show up in the cells. Is there something here I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, try doing creating a nib file (File-->New File-->User Interface-->View). Delete the "view" and drag a Table View Cell out.  Lay it out as you have described in your post. In your tableViewController do:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TVCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = tvCell;
    self.tvCell = nil;
}
```

The reason being, you cannot have 2 "viewControllers" on screen at the same time with the exception of Controllers of Controllers (Tab Bar, Navigation, SplitView). You are trying to put one view controller in another view controller right now.

Comment: Swapping out and using a nib did the trick, thanks. Note however I did get the loading of a VC as a subview as a cell working. I got it to load in the cell however upon selection of anything in that cell I got a run time error (bad access I believe it was). Regardless, the nib is the way to go, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
PhotoLocation *photoLocation_ = [self.storyboardinstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PhotoLocation"];

[photoLocation_.view setFrame:CGRectMake(115, 0, 210, 109)];

[cell addSubview:photoLocation_.view];

return cell;
```